# Give non-root user access to log into phpMyAdmin

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I'm attempting to give a non-root mysql user access to log into phpMyAdmin and only see the DB they have access to.

I've already looked at the following articles and tried their advice:
    [Configuring phpmyadmin for Multiple Users](http://alandoyle.com/tutorials/configuring-phpmyadmin-for-multiple-users/comment-page-1/#comment-8363)

```
[How to configure phpMyAdmin for multiple users][2]

[Is there a tool like phpMyAdmin which can be configured to access just a single database?][3]

[how to configure config.inc.php to have a loginform in phpmyadmin][4]

[phpMyAdmin setup on live server with usercontrol][5]

[MYSQL ERROR 1045][6]
```

I've granted the mysql user access with password to their DB and to select items in mysql db (as stated in one of the articles).  I have configed phpmyadmin to use cookie auth_type, I have a pma control user, I've granted the user from not just '%' but from localhost and IPs, etc.

When the user logs in, they get #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

My root user can log in fine to phpmyadmin.  The user that needs access to phpmyadmin can log in from the command line fine as well.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Server configuration problems are offtopic here. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the skip-name-resolve for my /etc/my.cnf and it worked.